# How to correctly cite a comment in an edit to a question

Tags: discussion

I currently have an open question on math.stackexchange, where I have receieved a helpful comment towards a solution.

I now wish to edit my original question by adding some further material and citing the helpful comment as the reason for doing so. Is it sufficient to [link the comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/how-to-link-to-a-comment), or is there a more correct approach?

Comment: Sure, it's "sufficient" to link the Comment, but it might be as much (or more) gratifying to the person who made the helpful suggestion to be *mentioned* in the revised paragraph.  Using the `@usernym` syntax will bring your revised Question to their attention (given that their Comment still exists on the Question).  Some related discussion was [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16807/is-it-bad-form-to-answer-a-question-using-someone-elses-previous-comments) and its links.

Comment: Okay thanks I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your question and add the further material under the heading "EDIT:" on a new line. You can link the comment there.